# What is the canonical age of Xena when she first appears on Hercules: TLJ, and by the end of her own series?

Tags: timeline, xena, hercules-the-legendary-journeys

The character of Xena from **Hercules: The Legendary Journeys** and **Xena: Warrior Princess** was introduced with a very extensive backstory; she was a villager who became a warrior by force who became a warlord, and a legend across several continents. Lucy Lawless started playing Xena at 27 years old in 1995.... but that doesn't necessarily mean it was the *character's* age.

In fact, due to everything that seemed to happen in Xena's personal history, it's **highly unlikely** that was the characters age!

By a year after she starts traveling with Gabrielle... which was, by most canonical and chronological accounts, 2 years after her first appearance on *Hercules: TLJ*... we find out Xena has Solen, a 10-11 year old son. This was done during her warlord days, and she left the child to be raised by the Centaurs. But... that would have put her, at *most,* at 19 when he was born.

I'm a little sketchy on the timeline of the series, but I don't think that lines up; either Xena was supposed to be traveling Asia, or *just* finishing a war with Caesar at the time. Given that a *lot* of the story was altered "on the fly" in the series as it progressed, such inconsistencies are to be expected, but...

Is there any canon answer to how old Xena was *exactly* when she first fought Hercules? Or if not, how old was her character meant to be when she started her *Warrior Princess* days with Gabrielle?

And considering there were a few time skips, how old would she have been by series end?

Answer (score 9):

[From Steve Sears (Xena writer)](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/xena/repost-steven-l-sears-chat-t7335.html):

> We actually discussed this at an early time in the series. I think we decided that Gabrielle was around seventeen and that Xena was in her early twenties. As the series went on, we managed to pile a lot of living in those twenty odd years of Xena!

Comment: Can this be counted as Word of God? Because again, it just feels... "off" that Xena was _early 20s_ and accomplished _all_ that in 4-6 years.

Answer (score 1):

I would say more so that when Xena defended her village she was around 14 . Then she took the surrounding villages as and then traveled to Rome and met Ceaser then back to Greece where she met Borias and had Solan at about 16.
And then stayed around Greece and turned really evil after the death of Akemi.
She then finally met Hercules at about 20 and became good.
And met Gabrielle at age 27 and Gabby was maybe 15.
When Xena met Solan she would have bewn about 28 or 29 and Solan about 12 or 13.

I think Xena died at about age 34 but it had been 68 years since she was born. 
Since Xena and Gabrielle slept for 25 years.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for any of this to back it up that you could [edit] in?